# jQuery and Django templates

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, django-views

Is it possible to display html formatted text (for example '**Hey!**') as html via jQuery? I`m getting this text from db. When im trying to do something like

```
   $('.course_content').find('.content').html('{{ course.description }}')
```

It looks like plain text

```
  <strong>Hey!</strong>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `safe` filter. An example usage is:

`{{course.description|safe|escape}}`

You can read up about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatefilter-safe)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because you are mixing server and client side execution. Django view code is executed in the server (so all the `{{ value }}` tags are replaced with the respective values), and what is returned to the web browser is just HTML. Then the javascript code is executed in the context of the HTML generated.

So, if you want to use client-side templates like you have on Django you can use something like [Handlebar.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/), which has a similar syntax.